# Why LazyColumn is recreated approximately every 30 objects?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm starting to try Jetpack Compose and was wondering why a simple list was so poorly optimised when I scrolled. Even in release build.
So I started adding logs and I realized that sometimes the list seemed to be recreating itself.

Here is my composable :

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun MissionsList() {
    val list = remember { (0..75).map { it.toString() } }
    LazyColumn(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(22.5.dp)
    ) {
        Log.e("LazyColumn", "CREATE")
        items(
            count = list.size,
            key = { list[it] }
        ) {
            Card(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(100.dp),
                elevation = 0.dp,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
            ) {
                Log.e("card", "${list[it]}")
                Text(
                    text = list[it],
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is output :

```
15:20:30.738 LazyColumn               E  CREATE
15:20:30.810 card                     E  0
15:20:30.828 card                     E  1
15:20:30.841 card                     E  2
15:20:30.866 card                     E  3
15:20:30.879 card                     E  4
15:20:31.250 Chip                     E  1
15:20:36.404 card                     E  6
15:20:36.496 card                     E  7
15:20:36.560 card                     E  8
15:20:36.645 card                     E  9
15:20:36.730 card                     E  10
15:20:36.840 card                     E  11
15:20:37.043 card                     E  12
15:20:38.324 card                     E  13
15:20:38.381 card                     E  14
15:20:38.417 card                     E  15
15:20:38.449 card                     E  16
15:20:38.478 card                     E  17
15:20:38.504 card                     E  18
15:20:38.529 card                     E  19
15:20:38.560 card                     E  20
15:20:38.570 card                     E  21
15:20:38.579 card                     E  22
15:20:38.610 card                     E  23
15:20:38.653 card                     E  24
15:20:38.685 card                     E  25
15:20:38.694 card                     E  26
15:20:38.717 card                     E  27
15:20:38.761 card                     E  28
15:20:38.782 card                     E  29
15:20:38.793 card                     E  30
15:20:38.820 card                     E  31
15:20:38.859 card                     E  32
15:20:38.892 card                     E  33
15:20:38.921 card                     E  34
15:20:38.972 card                     E  35
15:20:39.006 card                     E  36
15:20:39.020 LazyColumn               E  CREATE
15:20:39.027 card                     E  37
15:20:39.045 card                     E  30
15:20:39.047 card                     E  31
15:20:39.048 card                     E  34
15:20:39.066 card                     E  35
15:20:39.069 card                     E  32
15:20:39.070 card                     E  33
15:20:39.072 card                     E  36
15:20:39.131 card                     E  38
15:20:39.169 card                     E  39
15:20:39.218 card                     E  40
15:20:39.281 card                     E  41
15:20:39.354 card                     E  42
...
```

I noticed that about every 30 items the list is recreated.
What did I miss?

Comment: The recomposition is probably triggered one level up, where your this composable is called or the scroll somehow forces it to recompose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LazyColumn uses a sliding window to track the key for each index, which can cause the lambda that contains your log statement to be recalculated. That doesn't mean that all the work Compose/LazyColumn did to generate your UI is thrown out though, so this shouldn't cause any significant performance impact.

You mentioned seeing performance issues in a release build. If that's optimized with R8 and you're using baseline profiles, scrolling a list like this should be plenty performant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After a few hours, I understand better how recomposition works. And yes it is not because I see a log that the composable is recomposing. I'm using R8 but not baseline profiles at the moment even if I've read some documentation about it. What is strange is that performance are good en emulator but not on a real device. But if in my activity I change the theme of the phone everything starts to be smooth.